# Got “Blocked:mixed content” on HTTPS website

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

**What is the current behavior?**

I'm Running a Website using Webpack in Production.

I was surprised to see in Chrome console the following error about loading the js file which is mixed with weback and laravel-mix

[image]

**My questions:**

1. How can we have a mixed content on a website loaded using HTTPS protocol?
2. How can I fix the error? I don't plan to serve website over HTTP and I want my `js` to load properly both in development and production.

Comment: Check your webpack config file and make sure you're not using HTTP (without the S) anywhere in it ?

Answer (score 1):

From MDN documentation on [mixed content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content)

> To fix this type of error, all requests to HTTP content should be
>   removed and replaced with content served over HTTPS. Some common
>   examples of mixed content include JavaScript files, stylesheets,
>   images, videos, and other media.

Comment: this is build using webpack so we cant change tags to https!