# Rewrites/Redirects for AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, single-page-application, aws-amplify

Can anyone help me with setting up rewrites/redirects?

I have a route that is /privacy_policy

With no rewrite, I get access denied only on the hosted app.

Then I found this solution for it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

Added this to Amplify settings, and the page works fine. However, I have custom fonts in the directory that weren't loading in production.

I followed this: [React images load locally but not on AWS Amplify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64146914/react-images-load-locally-but-not-on-aws-amplify)

And changed the redirect from 200 to 404 rewrite. However, this then broke my fb login because fb curls my privacy policy and it returned a 404. How can I get both to work?